# Unexpected token ? in JSON at position x using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I am trying to parse a String to literal object using `JSON.parse` :

```
var o = JSON.parse(str);
```

I got this error  :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 362
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Know that the error occurs on the `?` of this portion :

```
{...
     "11. More Info":"http://www.mysilte.com/na5638\?lid=10064669521",
  ...
}
```

I try escaping `?` by the callback of `JSON.parse`:

```
var o = JSON.parse(str,function(k,v){
                return (typeof v ==='string')? v.replace('?','') : v;
 });
```

The same :( , does not work .. Anyone knows how to do this using `JSON.parse` or with any node.js package.

Comment: Please provide the complete string (as this exact string doesn't give any error)

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ "11. More Info":"http://www.mysilte.com/na5638?lid=10064669521" }))` works without error for me (on FF or chrome).

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/vLk7n78g/.

Comment: `{...
     "11. More Info":"http://www.mysilte.com/na5638\?lid=10064669521",
  ...
}`

Comment: @ASDFGerte : I miss anti-slash so `..a5638\?lid=1... ` and NOT `...a5638?lid=1....`

Comment: @FelixKling :  I miss anti-slash so `..a5638\?lid=1... ` and NOT `...a5638?lid=1....`

Comment: Well yes, `\?` is not a valid escape sequence in a string literal in JSON. How are you getting the JSON? The only way to produce invalid JSON is if you built in manually. Don't do that. Use your languages JSON library to generate it. Trying to fix that on the client side is the wrong approach.

Comment: @Dekel :  I miss anti-slash so `..a5638\?lid=1... ` and NOT `...a5638?lid=1....`

Comment: @FelixKling : How to do now ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI: Depends on how you get/generate the JSON. There is not much we can tell you besides "generate valid JSON".

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI, Did you check my answer? Will appreciate if you accept/vote it if it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your json-string is **not** a real json string (but probably close to) you might want to "fix" the `\\?` problem you got in your string.

Here is an example:

```js
a = '{"11. More Info":"http://www.mysilte.com/na5638\\?lid=10064669521"}'
try {
  JSON.parse(a)
} catch (e) {
  console.log("can't parse the string as JSON string")
}
json_obj = JSON.parse(a.replace("\\?", "?"))
console.log(json_obj)
```

I really don't recommend this and you should probably make sure you get a correct json-string before parsing it, but sometimes you don't have a control on the input you get, so this solution might help you).